# Git command for checkout new master and update master

Tags: git

I am not very clear about some of the git command, and here they are:

1. To checkout my newly created branch: "my_branch"
   `git pull origin master`
   `git checkout my_branch`
2. To update my branch daily:
   `git pull`

are my command correct? Thanks for helping.

Comment: "are my command correct?" What are you trying to accomplish in each situation? Which part are you not clear about? Have you read the documentation when you do `git help pull`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To checkout my newly created branch: "my_branch" `git pull origin master` `git checkout my_branch`

These two commands do two different things. `git pull origin master` pulls the `master` branch from the `origin` remote into your current branch. `git checkout my_branch` checks out a branch named `my_branch`. If you are only trying to checkout a branch that already exists then `git checkout my_branch` is enough. You don't need to do `git pull origin master` in this case.

> To update my branch daily: `git pull`

This will pull the remote tracking branch to your currently checkout out branch. By this I mean that the following two things are the same:

```
git checkout my_branch
git pull
```

and

```
git checkout my_branch
git pull origin my_branch
```

> are my command correct?

That depends on what you want to do. Your question doesn't clearly state your goals for each command. Hopefully the explanations above clarify what these commands do so that you can decide if they are correct for your situation. If not, please edit your question to explain what you want to accomplish.